# How to extract multiple ggplot from nested list and plot them like facet_grid?

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, patchwork

I have written a custom function which returns a list of `ggplot` with some data. Here is the function

```
custom_fun <- function(x = x){
  x = x
  # Calculate the length
  n <- length(x)
  
  # First half arranged in ascending order
  fh <- sort(x[1:(n/2)])
  
  # Second half arranged in ascending order
  sh <- sort(x[((n/2)+1):n])
  
  d <- cbind.data.frame(fh, sh)

  #Some calculations
  dis = sqrt(diff(d$fh)^2 + diff(d$sh)^2)
  sl = diff(d$sh) / diff(d$fh)
  
  #Plotting using ggplot2
    myplot <- function(mydf, xcol, ycol){
      ggplot2::ggplot(data = mydf, ggplot2::aes(x = {{xcol}}, y = {{ycol}})) +
        ggplot2::geom_point(color='red', alpha=0.3, size=2)+
        ggplot2::geom_segment(color="#69b3a2", 
                              ggplot2::aes(xend=c(tail({{xcol}}, n=-1), NA), 
                                  yend=c(tail({{ycol}}, n=-1), NA))
        ) +
        ggplot2::geom_abline (slope=1, linetype = "dashed", color="Red") +
        ggplot2::xlab(" ") +
        ggplot2::ylab(" ")
    }
  
  my_plot <- myplot(d, fh, sh)
  
  return(list(`Dis` = dis, `SL` = sl,
              `Plot` = my_plot))
}
```

I am using `lapply` to apply the function to multiple columns like

```
try <- lapply(iris[-5], custom_fun)
```

Now, how can I extract the ggplots and make multipanel plots like the following plot?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `patchwork` solution including modification of the position of the title, or any other theme element. (stealing the first part of @benson23 answer)

```
library(patchwork)
try_list <- lapply(iris[-5], custom_fun)

wrap_plots(lapply(names(try_list), \(x) try_list[[x]][["Plot"]]+ggtitle(x))) & 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5) )
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show a single plot with title?

Comment: sorry I don't understand the question.

Comment: Only `Sepal.Length` part with the title i.e. output of `custom_fun(iris$Sepal.Length)` with title.

Comment: instead of `names(try_list)` just use the vector of the names you want to include.  So replace `names(try_list)` with `"Sepal.Length"`

Answer (score 2):

You can first extract all plots, then use the `plotlist` argument in `ggarrange` from the `ggpubr` package.

To include the labels on top of each plot, first expand the plot margins in your `ggplot` codes, then play around with the `ggarrange(vjust)` parameter to get the best outcome.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)


custom_fun <- function(x = x){
  x = x
  # Calculate the length
  n <- length(x)
  
  # First half arranged in ascending order
  fh <- sort(x[1:(n/2)])
  
  # Second half arranged in ascending order
  sh <- sort(x[((n/2)+1):n])
  
  d <- cbind.data.frame(fh, sh)
  
  #Some calculations calculation
  dis = sqrt(diff(d$fh)^2 + diff(d$sh)^2)
  sl = diff(d$sh) / diff(d$fh)
  
  #Plotting using ggplot2
  myplot <- function(mydf, xcol, ycol){
    ggplot2::ggplot(data = mydf, ggplot2::aes(x = {{xcol}}, y = {{ycol}})) +
      ggplot2::geom_point(color='red', alpha=0.3, size=2)+
      ggplot2::geom_segment(color="#69b3a2", 
                            aes(xend=c(tail({{xcol}}, n=-1), NA), 
                                yend=c(tail({{ycol}}, n=-1), NA))
      ) +
      ggplot2::geom_abline (slope=1, linetype = "dashed", color="Red") +
      ggplot2::xlab(" ") +
      ggplot2::ylab(" ") +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1.5, 0, 0, 0), "lines")) # add this code
  }
  
  my_plot <- myplot(d, fh, sh)
  
  return(list(`Dis` = dis, `SL` = sl,
              `Plot` = my_plot))
}

try_list <- lapply(iris[-5], custom_fun)

ggarrange(plotlist = lapply(try_list, `[[`, "Plot"), labels = names(try_list), vjust = 1.5)
```

[image: ggarrange_plotlist]

Or iterating the plots in `plotlist` to add `ggtitle` (idea is from @George Savva)

```r
ggarrange(plotlist = lapply(names(try_list), \(x) try_list[[x]]$Plot + ggtitle(x)))
```

[image: ggtitle_plotlist]

Comment: How to place the plot labels above the plot aligned centrally?

Comment: @UseR10085 See my update, you may have to play around with different values to get the best outcome (similarly, play around with the `hjust` parameter to control the horizontal alignment of the labels) :)

Comment: Can't we add `ggtitle`?

Comment: @UseR10085 Based on your `myplot` function, I don't see how we can blend in `ggtitle`, because the function have no access to your column names. That's why I think unlisting your list of plots and do `patchwork` will give you the best control.